# How to run project locally with sqs or s3 but without entering credentials?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sqs-fifo

I have a repository that involves 5 people, and at this stage, we've decided to use SQS and S3 as Amazon services. The issue is that credentials are required for setting up and connecting to SQS and S3. While on the development environment, credentials are hidden from everyone, how can one run this locally on their machine without entering credentials? Otherwise, a connection refused error will occur.
I mean, when I run it locally, I just want to skip connection to AWS and skip using AWS maybe someone know how it works in real-world big projects?

Hence, my question is: have you encountered such a situation, and is it possible to test this locally without credentials? Are there specific configurations that might be needed?

I'm trying to run my project locally without connecting to Amazon SQS and S3, i.e., without entering credentials. What steps can I take to achieve this, and what alternatives are available for local testing?

Comment: When you say "run this locally on their machine", are you implying that you will use a library like [LocalStack](https://www.localstack.cloud/) that is a private implementation of the AWS APIs, so they are **not actually using AWS**? Even if you use LocalStack, you'll need credentials for LocalStack. Or are you wanting people to still connect with AWS.

Comment: You can't run SQS and S3 locally, so you would have to either change it to something else than SQS and S3, or suck it up and make more accounts with credentials for testing.